# Tht Aain’t Right... #2

Tags: chess, retrograde-analysis

I already have another, probably very easy, for you all again!

---

Task: State the rule/s that you believe are being broken based on the position and/or what clues I have/you think are being given. You must also use this rule to complete the given game.

The Position:

[image]

What To Do: Find four ways for white to checkmate black in one move. It is white to move, of course.

Comment: Your best puzzle so far IMO. Very well done!

Comment: Thanks! But why this one in particular?

Comment: 1. It's very clear and straightforward. 2. The correct answer doesn't use any sort of cheesy loopholes and there is only one correct answer. 3. The correct answer also relates to the title in a clever way that verifies the solution.

Comment: Not that your other puzzles have _not_ done these things, but I feel that this one is exemplary of the above traits.

Comment: I agree.  This is a very good puzzle

Comment: Also agree. +1 and $\color{orange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suspect the broken rule is

> jumping over one's own pieces.

Allowing the checkmates

> Qh5# or Qh4# or Rh3# or Rh2#

A hint pointing to this answer:

> The title is "Tht A**a**in't right". Notice how the "a" has jumped over other letters in order to move to the right.

Answer (score 8):

It might be

> [cylindrical chess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_chess)

so

> the h- and a-file are connected, and you can mate with Qb4-h4, Qb4-h2, Rc3-h3 and Rd2-h2.

This fits the clue in the title insofar that

> the 'a'-file lies to the right of the 'h'-file.

Comment: This would lead to at least 7 mates, not 4.

Comment: Did I really miss three additional mates? I still can't see them ...

Comment: There would be additional Q moves, wrapping around along diagonals as well as straight across ranks.  (Meta: is it possible to put spoiler tags in comments?)

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Note that the Qa5 can't move to give check without allowing the black king to escape to the a file

Comment: Another one (not nearly as good as yours or the chosen answer) would be Queens and Kings are allowed to move cylindrically and jump over pieces

Comment: @C.Martin usually to spoiler comments, we use [rot13.com](http://rot13.com) and would communicate the phrase "hidden text" like so: Rot13(uvqqra grkg).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe:

> Rule:
>  The towers move like bishops.

So:

> Checkmates:
>  Qa5-f5 # or Qb4-e4 # or Qb4-b1 # or Pg5-g6 #

Because:

> Hints:
>  The third letter of the first word goes to the second letter of the second word (diagonally). The first word begins with T(ower), and does not move to the 'right', but moves as 'aa', letter one plus letter one, letter two, (B)ishop.

Comment: The towers are both on black tiles, which is also a reason your rule can't work out.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the rules being broken are that

> the board is not described traditionally, with the ranks described with letters and the files described with numbers

and

> the board was set up with a black square in the bottom right hand corner (1a in this game's notation) rather than white as it should be.

This leads to checkmate by

> promoting any of the white pawns to a rook or queen.

Comment: @RewanDemontay Thank you for your acknowledgement although, to be pedantic, the puzzle doesn't state that the moves are invalid, just that at least one rule is being broken.  The layout at the start of the game is a rule of chess.  If I'm going to be ultrapedantic, you ask which rule/s *are* being broken rather than ones which *will* be broken by the next move.

I could also offer the suggestion that the 'A'; has moved